# Execute global batch job from installed package

Tags: managed-package, batch, global-methods

How to execute global batch job  from installed package:

```
NS__BirthdayBatch bb = new NS__BirthdayBatch();
Database.executeBatch(vb);
```

When I try ti run this code in dev console or workbench I am getting this error:

```
COMPILE ERROR: Invalid type: NS__BirthdayBatch
LINE: 1 COLUMN: 45
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Classes are namespace prefixed with a dot rather than double underscores. Your code should be:

```
NS.BirthdayBatch bb = new NS.BirthdayBatch();
Database.executeBatch(bb);
```